# Nodejs Elasticsearch errors are not showing

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am facing problem with nodejs elasticsearch library. Below code is working and giving result if I remove **console.log(hello);** But if I add this then no error is coming. I am expecting error message of undefined variable "hello". I need to see error message for debugging purpose. What could be the reason?

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'http://mywebsite.com',
  // log: 'trace'
});


body = {};

esClient.search({
          index: 'test',
          type: 'data',
          body: body
        }).then(function (resp) {

            console.log(hello);
            console.log(resp);    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the code reaches inside the  `then` function ? maybe search is throwing a error and you have no `catch` block ???

try :

```
esClient.search({...})
        .then(function (resp) {

            console.log(hello);
            console.log(resp);    
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);    
        });
```

see if you getting any error then ?

Comment: Yes I was missing "catch" block. Thanks :)